# install airflow on compute engine

Tags: installation, airflow, google-compute-engine, airflow-2.x

I would like to ask if any of you have experience installing Airflow on Compute Engine. I have been searching for instructions on Google and asking ChatGPT, but I have not been successful so far. I would like to know the correct sequence of commands for installing Airflow on Compute Engine. I believe my installation issues may be due to my lack of understanding of the proper installation steps for Airflow. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Airflow installation is documented. If you have a problem, then post a question: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/index.html

Comment: My issue is that I don't understand the process of installing Airflow, and in the provided link, I couldn't find the installation steps specifically for Compute Engine. I apologize for being a beginner. Previously, I worked as a data analyst and I am currently learning to become a data engineer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow allows users to create workflows as Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAGs) of tasks tied together to create workflows. Airflow can connect with multiple data sources and send alerts via email/notification about the Job’s status.

Integrating Airflow on Google Compute Engine is easily done in 5 steps:

**Step-1 :** create a Compute Engine Instance to set up Google Airflow Integration

- Log in to Cloud Console, and on the search box, Search for “Create an Instance“.
- Click on New VM Instance, provide the Instance’s name, and select the instances as per your requirement. For example : Machine type can be e2-standard-2 (2vCPU, 8 GB Memory). Image : Debian 1.0 and 50 GB HDD
- Click Create to create Compute Engine VM Instance.

Check out the [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage) to create a Compute Engine VM instance using the gcloud command line.

**Step-2 :** Install Apache Airflow

- Once the Instance is created, click the SSH to start a terminal.
- Once the terminal is up and running, upgrade the machine and install Python3 by running the following commands.

  `sudo apt update`

  `sudo apt -y upgrade`

  `sudo apt-get install wget`

  `sudo apt install -y python3-pip`

You can use either conda or miniconda to create a virtual environment for Google Airflow Integration.  Refer to the [doc](https://hevodata.com/learn/google-airflow/#s2) written by Vishal Agarwal to run the commands for creating a virtual environment and installing Airflow.

**Step-3 :** Setting Up Airflow

After successful installation of Airflow you need to set-up and initialize the Airflow. Run the following command for successful creation of admin user of Airflow.

`airflow db init airflow users create -r Admin -u <username> -p <password> -e <email> -f <first name> -l <last name>`

**Step- 4:** Open Firewall

Airflow runs only on port **8080**. So, In the GCP console, Navigate to the **VPC Network** -> Click on **Firewall** and create a port rule. Add port 8080 under **TCP** and click [**Create Rule**](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall#create_a_firewall_ingress_rule) in the Port rule.

On the Compute Instance, add the Firewall rule to access port 8080.

**Step-5:** Start Airflow

Once the Firewall is set up correctly. Start the Airflow Webserver by the following command:

`airflow webserver -p 8080`

Open another terminal and start the Airflow Scheduler:

`export AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/user/airflow_demo  cd airflow_demo  conda activate airflow_demo  airflow db init  airflow scheduler`

Once the scheduler is started. Open Airflow console from browser. Go to `https://<vm-IP-address>:8080.`

Give the username and password we created in Step 3. Now you can create DAGs in Airflow UI.